# adding windows form application to my site sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

i'm yousing Visual web part to creat my application in my site but i would like to addings windows form solutions to my site

can you hel me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by Windows Forms you mean .ASPX with code behind, then you will not be able to do this in SharePoint Online. Custom code solutions are not allowed there.

Comment: i would like to create an application sharepoint edit and write document .doc so i try to do it by asp.net but i can't find "openfiledialog" to complete my application so i decide to work with form application